# How to safely do a factory reset, lend my iPad, then restore it?

Tags: backup, restore, ipad

Someone wants to borrow my iPad2 and I'd like to

- make a complete backup of it
- do a factory reset
- let my acquaintance generate their own AppleID and use the device for a day
- after the device is returned restore my backed up snapshot and continue from where I was at the time of the backup.

Is this feasible at all? Would I need anything else for this beside iTunes plugged into a Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that should work fine.

1. Do your full backup
2. Go into General -> reset ->reset all content and settings

This COMPLETELY wipes the IOS device so your friend will set it up as if it were new.

When you get it back ask him to do the same thing first, in case they set a password. Sometimes if you have a PIN set you have to enter that to wipe it.

But your scenario should work fine

Comment: I'm using 3 browsers with several tabs open in each. Would these be backed up as well? I'd like to inform you that although I'm already very grateful for your kind help, I'll only be able to accept this answer once I get back my iPad and successfully restore the backup.

Comment: I honestly don't know if backups save the state of the browser. It has never been important to me nor have I noticed it, but that's just me. Perhaps someone else knows?